# Name the Late 1990s Era, Non-Signature-based, Israeli Antivirus Company/Product

Tags: anti-virus

There was a computer security company back approximately 10 years ago marketing a non-signature based antivirus & intrusion detection software package for Windows.  I cannot remember the name, and haven't had much luck with google searches to find it either.

Can anyone remember the name of this product?

Comment: This feature is called "heuristics" - trying to analyze behaviour of applications to see if it is suspicious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Invircible](http://www.invircible.com/invircible.php)

> InVircible ™ is a security software
>   package to protect personal computers
>   and PC networks from being attacked by
>   virus or other forms of malicious
>   code. InVircible is based on unique
>   and proven generic technology, that
>   provides for its exceptional
>   performance, without depending on
>   updates.

Comment: Also, there's some interesting analysis here: http://www.dmuth.org/virus/papers/vircing-the-invircible.html

Comment: @ Jess, you can edit your post to include that analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Antivirus Plus from Iris? or EliaShim's ViruSafe?